# Unexpected behavior of AES decryption

Tags: .net, postgresql, exception, encryption, utf-8

**The problem:** I have implemented some functionality that does decryption at specific events, but **SOMETIMES** it throws unexpected and unexplained exceptions.

**Flow:** A master key/iv is fetched then data (from a PostgreSQL database is fetched) and decoded from base64 and then decrypted and then decompressed and decoded again. So **summarizing** it goes like this:

1. Fetch Key/Iv
2. Decode From Base64
3. Decrypt with AES-256 CBC
4. Decompress from Gzip **(At this point it fails sometimes)**
5. Decode again to UTF-8

This is the code

```cs
public async Task<byte[]> PrivateDecrypt(long userId, byte[] data)
{
   var key = await this.GetOrAddPrivateEncryptionKey(userId);
   var keyBytes = key.ToUTF8Bytes();
   var (cipher, ivBytes) = data.ExtractIVPadding();

   var decrypted = await cipher
      .AESDecryptAndDecompressAsync(keyBytes, ivBytes)
      .ConfigureAwait(false);

   return decrypted;
}
```

```cs
public static byte[] FromBase64(this string base64) => Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
```

```cs
public static async Task<byte[]> AESDecryptAndDecompressAsync(this byte[] cipher, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
   if (cipher == null || cipher.Length <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cipher), "incorrect data");

   if (key == null || key.Length != 32)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key), "incorrect key");

   if (iv == null || iv.Length != 16)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iv), "incorrect iv");

   using var aesAlg = Aes.Create();

   aesAlg.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
   aesAlg.KeySize = 256;

   aesAlg.Key = key;
   aesAlg.IV = iv;
   aesAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

   using var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);

   using (var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream())
   {
      using (var encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(cipher))
      {
         using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
         {
            using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(cryptoStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
               await gzipStream.CopyToAsync(decompressedStream).ConfigureAwait(false);

            return decompressedStream.ToArray();
         }           
      }           
   }
}
```

This is part of the exception stack trace I receive

```cs
    System.IO.InvalidDataException: The archive entry was compressed using an unsupported compression method.
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.Inflate(FlushCode flushCode)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.ReadInflateOutput(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length, FlushCode flushCode, Int32& bytesRead)
   at System.IO.Compression.Inflater.InflateVerified(Byte* bufPtr, Int32 length)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.CopyToStream.WriteAsyncCore(ReadOnlyMemory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream.CopyToAsyncInternal(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.CopyToStream.CopyFromSourceToDestinationAsync()
   at Trading.Tools.Bytes.EncryptionExtensions.AESDecryptAndDecompressAsync(Byte[] cipher, Byte[] key, Byte[] iv) in /src/Trading.Tools/Bytes/EncryptionExtensions.cs:line 207
   at Trading.Web.Commons.Encryption.LocalEncryptionService.PrivateDecrypt(Int64 userId, Byte[] data) in /src/Trading.Web.Commons/Encryption/LocalEncryptionService.cs:line 107
```

As you can see from the stacktrace the problem lies in the **decompression** layer AFTER the decryption.

**Hypothesis:**

1. This code I can say for sure that it works
2. This exception that I encounter happens quite rarely
3. Data in database is correct, otherwise it would never work

**My thoughts:**

1. I believe that due to probabilistic nature of the problem then this can be a race condition. There are 2 possibilities I see:

- Either the database doesn't return me the full string and it escapes some character by mistake, but then how does decryption work ?
- Either decryption returns weird results sometimes which leads me to think that even if there are separate instances there is still a shared state somewhere ?

**Additional Info:**

1. I'm using EFCore 8.0.2 for fetching from database
2. I'm using .NET Core 8.0.3
3. I'm using PostgreSQL 16.1-bullseye

**UPDATE 1:** I've updated the code to @Charlieface suggestions, but unfortunately I still face the same issues

**UPDATE 2:** I replaced all the encryption logic with BouncyCastle Nuget and got rid of the issue. I did not have this problem prior to 8.0.3 so I only can assume it was because of the latest patch

Comment: What does `DecompressFromGzip` do? Can you show the code that does the encryption? And why is Postgres and EF Core relevant, that's just the backing store?

Comment: There are a huge number of side issues and red flags, possibly none will fix your issue: Why store Base64 in the database, rather than a binary blob? Using the same IV across all encryption is insecure, and obviates the point of the IV. Why are the key and IV stored as strings not byte arrays also (bear in mind many byte sequences are not valid strings)? You shouldn't use an intervening `MemoryStream`, just pass the `cryptoStream` all the way to the `GZipStream` without disposing.

Comment: in reply to @Charlieface , I understand your concern about IV. I can assure you this will not be the final implementarion and the ivs will be dynamically generated. However the issue cannot be related to this. As of the other things you proposed I will try the suggestions and come back with an answer. Moreover the iv and key are generated using writable characters just for debugging so they can be converted to utf8

Comment: @Charlieface I've done the changes thereby eliminating the reallocation of intermediate bytes and also changed from Text columns to ByteA (not seeing any meaningful impact here).. but the error still persists

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I replaced all the encryption logic with BouncyCastle Nuget and got rid of the issue. I did not have this problem prior to 8.0.3 so I only can assume it was because of the latest patch

Below is the **only** change I've made.

```cs
public static async Task<byte[]> AESDecryptAndDecompressAsync(this byte[] cipher, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
{
   if (cipher == null || cipher.Length <= 0)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(cipher), "incorrect data");

   if (key == null || key.Length != 32)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(key), "incorrect key");

   if (iv == null || iv.Length != 16)
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(iv), "incorrect iv");

   var cipherEngine = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new CbcBlockCipher(new AesEngine()), new Pkcs7Padding());
   cipherEngine.Init(false, new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(key), iv));

   var decryptedBytes = new byte[cipherEngine.GetOutputSize(cipher.Length)];
   var len = cipherEngine.ProcessBytes(cipher, 0, cipher.Length, decryptedBytes, 0);
   len += cipherEngine.DoFinal(decryptedBytes, len);

   var result = new byte[len];
   Array.Copy(decryptedBytes, result, len);

   using var decompressedStream = new MemoryStream();
   using (var ms = new MemoryStream(result))
   {
      using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(ms, CompressionMode.Decompress))
         await gzipStream.CopyToAsync(decompressedStream).ConfigureAwait(false);
   }

   return decompressedStream.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: No, it's a bug in the code. You didn't just change the library, you changed your own code to match the new API. If AES had issues, all developers would notice because they wouldn't be able to read the data they had already encrypted

Comment: I did not classify it as a bug, I said it happens somewhat with low frequency, very rarely. And If my code is not correct you can take a look and point out what's wrong with it. Otherwise if there is no issue with my code and neither does .NET Runtime have any issue (probably not even related with AES in the first place) why would it work changing the library ?

Comment: You didn't post a reproducible example - code that encrypts and decrypts the same data, something *we* can run and reproduce the problem

Comment: `why would it work changing the library` because you changed the rest of your code to accommodate the new library. That new code doesn't work the same way the old one did. You only posted half the code so we can't know what's different

Comment: Added changes to my answer

Comment: Why dont you post a reproducible example instead, if not it is very hard to find out which part of your code is wrong.